# How do you receive outgoing call in broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to identify and transfer to an activity after an outgoing call is initiated. I used `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` in the Intent filter. However how csn I identify that the call is outgoing. I did this for an incoming call (as seen below) but what can I use instead of `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`.

```
public class OutgoingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, OutgoingCallScreenDisplay.class);
            i.putExtras(intent);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class OutgoingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
           // If it is to call (outgoing)
           Intent i = new Intent(context, OutgoingCallScreenDisplay.class);
           i.putExtras(intent);
           i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL** is a constant declare in the `Intent` class, not in `TelephonyManager`. When an outgoing call appears, then the system broadcasts an intent with this constant. If you really want to catch an outgoing call by using `TelephonyManager` then do this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);   
tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch(state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if(incomingNumber==null) {
                    //outgoing call
                } else {
                    //incoming call
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                if(incomingNumber==null) {
                    //outgoing call
                } else {
                    //incoming call
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks it worked well! But now I am receiving the default screen from the system(see above screenshot) and only after I am getting my customized activity. How can I hide/override the screen with my activity?

Comment: @ if you want to replace this screen then it's possible only by using telephony AIDL file..

Comment: Best example of `ITelephony.aidl` :[mylockforandroid](http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/source/browse/trunk/phone/?r=317)

Comment: any specific project that will help me with outgoing call?

Comment: Bad answer as this work also requires adding the broadcast reciever to manifest.

Answer (score 4):

**Detect outgoing phone call event**

**1. Create OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(OutgoingCallReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), intent.toString());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing call catched!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //TODO: Handle outgoing call event here
    }
}
```

**2. Register OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**3. Add permission in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Comment: what is the permission for? I managed to fetch the outgoing call without it.

Comment: @Satya It doesn't work for me. Tested in an ASUS Zenfone 2 with Android 6.0.1