# How to get the result of a phone call in Android

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm trying to make a phone call programmaticaly and get the result of a call in code. I'm making the call this way:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + EmergenciesConfigActivity.contactList.get(i).getTelf_number().trim()));
    startActivity(i);
```

I've thought about use startActivityForResult method, but i couldn't guess how to configure onActivityResult method.

Comment: you need to lunch an application from another application.
see [this question's answers][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3872063/3014036

Comment: Define `the result of a phone call`...

Comment: I want to know if the call was answered or not. Thanks.

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9569750/3168859) and tell me if that helps..

Comment: Hello Lal, thanks. I already found several examples using BroadcastReceiver, but i already have one working in the same activity, so I was just wondering if it could be made in onActivityResult method.

Comment: Finally the TelephonyMaganer solution suited perfectly in the activity. Thank u very much.