# How to prevent and USSD code from running?

Tags: java, android, ussd

I want to see how can I prevent a specific USSD code from running in android java?

for example if the user dials *1234# an error pops or just make it not working.

I want to create an application that prevents dangerous USSD codes from running ... any thing?

thanks,

Comment: please show your code otherwise, people won't help you

Comment: Generally speaking, blocking the user from exercising basic functionality like this is not something official versions of Android are intended to permit a 3rd party application to do. You would probably have to implement this as a modification to a custom built variation of Android, which limits applicability to those willing to install this on devices you have built a custom version for... in other words, unless you have a driving need on a particular device your efforts are most likely better spent on other problems were your goals are not in conflict with the design of the operating system.

Comment: This might be possible as you can [set up a BroadcastListener for outgoing calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569118/how-do-you-receive-outgoing-call-in-broadcastreceiver) and [process the Broadcast](http://android-developers.blogspot.fi/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html). (Or I might be wrong, which is why I won't write a proper answer. I haven't tried this myself.)