# android - cannot receive CALL intent in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, action, phone-call

I have created a **BroadcastReceiver** to detect CALL action.

`android.intent.action.CALL` intent is received when it declared in Activity.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.xxx.yyy.CallCatcherActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But, it doesn't work on **BroadcastReceiver** or **Service**.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name="PhoneCallListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**PhoneCallListener.java**

```
public class PhoneCallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("-", intent.getAction() + " received");

        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.CALL")) {
                Log.d("-", "+ CALL action received!!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, list your application permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action CALL and action DIAL are used to start an `Activity`, these actions are NOT used in broadcast `Intent`s. There are separate `Intent`s used for starting `Activity`, `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver`s, and they have nothing to do with each other.

See [How do you receive outgoing call in broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569118/how-do-you-receive-outgoing-call-in-broadcastreceiver) for more details about how to catch `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` and how to use the `PhoneStateListener` to detect changes in call state.

Also see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548416/Detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-on-And for a tutorial on detecting incoming and outgoing calls.